# Unable to use Vue instance in app.js Laravel 8

Tags: vue.js, laravel-8, inertiajs

I am trying to use the Vue.mixin function in app.js but failed.

I have tried window.Vue = required('vue') and import Vue from 'vue' but still failed to use the mixin functionality.

I am using laravel 8 with inertia js stack & vuejs 3.